# ios automatically segue from one screen to another

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

So I have learnt how to segue from one screen to another when user presses a button. This is all handled in StoryBoard by literally pointing the button to the next screen.

However I would like to have a page that will automatically segue to another page after some data has been downloaded (so no user interaction).

What method call do I need to call from my ViewController class so that it calls the segue to be performed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `segue` from `firstviewcontroller`(data download view controller) to another `viewcontroller`. give segue the `identifier` e.g. nextView

now in the method where data gets downloaded, after the download you can call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];
```

and in `prepareForSegue:` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nextView"]) 
    {
        NextViewController *nextVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        //pass any data to next view here

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes thats the call. I also realised that this code will only work when the actuall Segue that I create on Storyboard is "Modal". It will not work if it is "Push". But this means that I lose my Navigation Controller and there is now no back button on the new View that I have just segued to using modal.

Comment: it can work in "Push" also, have u embed your firstviewcontroller in UINavigationcontroller, you can do it by selecting your view controller in storyboard-> Editor-Embed in->Navigation Controller. Then try push segue it will work

Comment: Hi, Actually this does not work as you describe. I have simple example. 3 VC the first is set as the UINavigationController and has a button to the second View. In the second view a programatic segue is to be performed to go to the the 3rd view. Each View is connected by a Push Segue. What happens is that the programatic Segue gets the following error "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar".

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813091/nested-push-animation-can-result-in-corrupted-navigation-bar-multiple-warning

Answer (score 1):

You can call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```