# From view controller to PageViewController

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

i've got a `UIViewControllers` with two `UIButtons`, i want to know how to pass from this `UIViewController` to my `UIPageViewController`, 
i tried to link the `UIButton` to my `UIPageViewController` from the storyboard but it gives me this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'Guide''

how should i do?

**EDIT**

```
- (IBAction)goToGuide:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToGuide" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nextView"])
    {
        FirstLaunch *fLaunch = [segue destinationViewController];
        //pass any data to next view here

    }
}
```

Added this to my `UIViewController` and added the identifier in my storyboard a connection between the view controller and the `UIPageViewController` and set the identifier to goToGuide, but same error..

**UP**

**EDIT2**

```
- (IBAction)goToGuide:(id)sender{

    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:Guide animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:self];
}
```

It says, property windows not found on object of type FirstLaunch

Answer (score 0):

Give the segue identifer in the storyboard, you must have missed it.

Check this answer
[ios automatically segue from one screen to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857726/ios-automatically-segue-from-one-screen-to-another)

Comment: @Jack_usti What is the identifier you have given in StoryBoard to the segue, check the IB in the storyboard. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: @Jack_usti Replace the line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToGuide" sender:self]; with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];

Comment: ok now this error: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'NextView'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.' @UtsavParkih

Comment: @Jack_usti It is because you have not initialised a navigation controller. You need to make your home screen rootViewController for the navigation controller and then you can perform this operation.

Comment: how should i do that? @UtsavParkih

Comment: This is how i am doing it....                                                      UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
RunningViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];